# Why does `validates_associated` exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[This section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated) of railsguide says:

> You should use this helper when your model has associations with other models and they also need to be validated.

So I thought validation of associated models wouldn't be run without  `validates_associated`.

But actually, It was run without it.

There are two models, School and Student.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  validates :name,  presence: true
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  validates :name,  presence: true
end
```

On rails console,

```
school = School.new
=> #<School id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

school.students << Student.new
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Student id: nil, name: nil, school_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>

school.name = "test shcool"
=> "test shcool"

school.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false

school.errors.full_messages
=> ["Students is invalid"]
```

If with validates_associated like below:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  validates :name,  presence: true
  validates_associated :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  validates :name,  presence: true
end
```

On rails console, I ran the exact same commands as above. But the last command `school.errors.full_messages` returned different result. (It is strange that there are duplicate error messages.)

```
school.errors.full_messages
=> ["Students is invalid", "Students is invalid"]
```

My questions are

1. Is this a RailsGuide's mistake?
2. Why does `validates_associated` exist?

Or do I have any mistaken idea?

My environment is

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
Rails 4.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

it checks to see if the associated objects are valid before saving

Comment: But as I wrote above, even without `validates_associated`, validation of associated object was run.

Comment: @tarky the first modal won't save unless the child modals saves.

Comment: Thanks!
But as I wrote above, regardless of whether or not to use `validates_associated`, the first model wasn't saved.

Comment: `validates_associated` is only for updates, not for create. On create validation is always run.